# How to execute async operations sequentially with c++ boost::asio?

Tags: c++, boost

I would like to have a way to add async tasks form multiple threads and execute them sequentially in a c++ boost::asio application.

**Update:** I would like to make a server-to-server communication with only one persistent socket between them and I need to sequence the multiple requests trough it. It needs to keep the incoming request in a queue, fire the top one / wait for it response and pick up the next.    I'm trying to avoid using [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/) because it needs a dedicated thread.

**Update2:** Ok, Here is with what I ended up: The concurrent worker threads are "queued" for the use of the server-to-server socket with a simple mutex. The communication is blocking write/wait for response/read then release the mutex. Simple isn't it :)

Comment: I would love to have that, too!

Answer (score 1):

From the ASIO [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html):

> Asynchronous completion handlers will only be called from threads that
>   are currently calling io_service::run().

If you're already calling `io_service::run()` from multiple threads, you can wrap your async calls in an `io_service::strand` as described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html).

Comment: Actually strand is sequencing only synchronous tasks. You can't sequence async tasks with strand. Here is an example. a service receivs requests and it needs to ask a secondary service to complete the request. I would like to sequence the request to the secondarily service one async request/async response at a time.

Comment: @Roskoto: I don't think that's true.  If you look at the Timer 5 example, a strand is used to synchronize calls to async_wait() of two different deadline_timers in two different threads.  When you speak of a secondary service are you talking about another io_service object?  If so, perhaps the solution is to use a single io_service object that is shared by your threads.  Then you should be able to synchronize your async tasks using a strand.  Or am I not understanding something?

Comment: I don't think Timer.5 is a good example. It starts both timers simultaneously and only synchronize the responses. Yes I'm having only one io_service run in multiple threads

Comment: @Roskoto: I see you added some more info about what you're trying to accomplish but I guess I just don't understand.  I wish I could be more help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly either, but what's wrong with the approach in the [client chat example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_client.cpp)? Messages are posted to the io_service thread, queued while a write is in progress and popped/sent in the write completion handler. If more messages were added in the meantime, the write handler launches the next async write.

Based on your comment to Sean, I also don't understand the benefit of having multiple threads calling io_service::run since you can only execute one async_write/async_read on one persistent socket at a time i.e. you can only call async_write again once the handler has returned? The number of calling threads might require you to lock the queue with a mutex though.

AFAICT the benefit of having multiple threads calling io_service::run is to increase the scalability of a server that is serving multiple requests simultaneously.

Comment: The sample only sequence the requests without waiting any responses.

Comment: @Roskoto: By "responses" do you mean responses to the write from the server? If so, you can just as well launch an async_read in the write completion handler?